# how can I ref a model that is in another folder?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

for example the nexts schemas are in diferent folders like these:

```
cr/user
lms/content
```

this is the schemaContent

```
user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'cr/user'
    }
```

How can I ref user from Content?

because when I used cr/user I get an error "Schema hasn't been registered for model"

I need just populate user from content like `Content.find().populate({ path: 'users' })` Keeping user in the folder called cr and content in the folder called lms

Comment: in some place that `user` model registered like `mongoose.model("something",Userschema) ` something like that.
you have to use that `something` name. like you used before.
in case there is multple database. and they have different registered model. it wil be different.

Comment: if I put the user in the same folder as lms/user and lms/content, user and content will be in the same folder(lms), so this will works ref: 'cr/user'. When the Schemas are in different folder won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to nest documents. Try below approach to nest document.

i will assume the directories `cr` and `lms` are inside the directory called `demoproject`

**demoproject/cr/user.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name:{
        type : String,
        required: true
    }
});
const User = mongoose.model("User",UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

**demoproject/lms/content.js**

`./../cr/user` - go back from `lms` directory and get into `cr/user`

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const User = require("./../cr/user");
const ContentSchema = new Schema({
    type:{
        type : String,
        required: true
    },
    users : [{
        type  : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref : "User"
    }]
});
const Content = mongoose.model("Content",ContentSchema);
module.exports = Content;
```

> How can I ref user from Content?

i hope your question is clear now. Keep reading below

**Moment of truth**

Lets insert data by using these two models.

Create a file to write mongo queries (`demoproject/index.js`).

- As `User model` is nested into `Content model`, we need to first save data into `User model`
- Then save data into `Content model`
- Now push data into `users` object present in Content Model `contentdata.users.push(userdata);`
- Donot forget to save the `contentdata` after pushing the userdata object into contentdata `contentdata.save();`

**demoproject/index.js**

```
const User = require("./cr/user");
const Content = require("./lms/content");

const userobj = new User({name : "rockyjohnson"});
const contentobj = new Content({type : "gloves"});

userobj.save().then((userdata)=>{
    contentobj.save().then((contentdata)=>{
        contentdata.users.push(userdata);
        contentdata.save();
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log("err while saving contentdata ", err);
    })
}).catch((err)=>{
    console.log("err while saving userdata ", err);
})
```

**Mongodb output**
[image]

That is all

**Update:** answer for the second question

`find` returns an `array` object in its promise. i'm able to extract `users` object present inside `Content model` here. Below is the query i used to verify

```
Content.find().then((data)=>{
    data.forEach(element => {
        console.log("element users ",element.users); // element.users contains all id's stored in the users array
    });
}).catch((err)=>{
    console.log("err  ",err);
})
```

Comment: There is a problem. I need to populate User from content. So if I use in ContentSchema  this -------    const User = require("./../cr/user"); --------and after I try to populate user from content like Content.find().populate('users') it will show an error 'MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model'

Comment: update your question with the full mongoose query  and provide all details for debugging

Comment: I need just to populate User from content

Comment: To be clearer try to populate users from Content  with the answer of divine and see if it works

Comment: it's strange because this 'console.log("element users ",element.users); ' only shows the objectId of user, it does not show   the complete object like name and _id

Comment: @santiago your original question has been answered i believe.

Comment: yeah the question has been answered but this Content.find().then((data)=>{
    data.forEach(element => {
        console.log("element users ",element.users);  does not show the complete object of user like name and _id of user

Comment: @santiago i cant see this in your question. where is it? read this post to understand how to ask a question on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The problem was that user was with lowercase (user). User needed to be uppercase(User).  I mean

Comment: @santiago you are talking about 'MissingSchemaError' is it?

Comment: no. in contentSchema the ref was 'ref:user' but that was wrong. Should be 'ref: User' because the schema when is exported 'mongose.model('User',UserSchema)' the word 'User' is with UpperCase